# How to detect vMotion from linux machine + rhel 7.2

Tags: vmware-esxi, redhat, vmware-vsphere, rhel7, vmotion

We have a couple of Linux Red Hat virtual machines running on top of the VMware ESXi cluster.

We aren't sure is vMotion configured or not.

Is it possible to identify if vMotion is configured or activated, from within the guest Linux Red Hat OS itself?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't query cluster settings directly within a VM, therefore whether DRS is configured, or the host settings to see if vMotion is configured, but you used to be able to find out the name of the host a VM was running on and if you captured this over a period of time and saw that the host name changed then you can be sure that either a manual or automatic vMotion happened.

Comment: you said "ut you used to be able to find out the name of the host a VM was running on and if you captured this over a period of time"  , please let me know how to capture the name?

Comment: I've not tried it for several versions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, I don't think live migration settings are exposed to VMware guests. The easy way would be with `vmware-toolbox-cmd`, and I do not see anything relevant there.

Rather, write automation scripts to check this using the vSphere API. If live migration configuration is important to you, you can ask for a read only user to verify.

Comment: can you maybe you help me to understand why vmotion change the date on the machine

Comment: second if this is the real case then what is the solution from redhat side?

Comment: Time sync is a different question, but see http://www.vmware.com/files/pdf/Timekeeping-In-VirtualMachines.pdf.  I already gave an answer: it is not easy on the guest, so don't and use the vSphere API.